# how to maintain a version to the table data in Postgres from java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, postgresql-9.3

I need maintain two tables one with the data and one with Versions.
So each time when a new record Inserted/Deleted  from the table I need to update the version in the other table.
How to do it from Java/JPA ?
Database is Postgres.

Comment: http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Comment: You could use a trigger and an audit table: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/ or http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html or https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Answer (score 1):

If Java-only, you do it by executing *all* the SQL statements necessary to accomplish the changes you want to *both* tables, in the same database transaction.

Alternatively, if you want updates to main table to auto-replicate to version table, create a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html) on the main table.